# How to Call HTML Id in App Maker

Tags: google-app-maker

Below code, I have incorporated into Google App script and Deployed as a web app and it works perfectly fine how can I use this code n App maker

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="browser"></div>
    <div id="os"></div>
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/faisalman/ua-parser-js/master/dist/ua-parser.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      var parser = new UAParser();
      parser.setUA("<?= HtmlService.getUserAgent(); ?>");
      var result = parser.getResult();
      document.getElementById("browser").textContent = result.browser.name + " v" + result.browser.major;
      document.getElementById("os").textContent = result.os.name + " v" + result.os.version;
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve the use of this library, please do the following:

Step 1 - Add the library to the **app settings** as shown below:
[image]

Step 2 - Add an **HTML widget** to a page, as shown below:
[image]

Step 3 - Please check the **allowUnsafeHtml** checkbox of the HTML widget as shown below:
[image]

Step 4 - Add the following markup to the **HTML widget html value**:

```
<div id="browser"></div>
<div id="os"></div>
```

[image]

Step 5 - Add the following code to the **onAttach** event of the HTML widget:

```
var parser = new UAParser();
var result = parser.getResult();
document.getElementById("browser").textContent = result.browser.name + " v" + result.browser.major;
document.getElementById("os").textContent = result.os.name + " v" + result.os.version;
```

[image]

Now, go ahead and preview your app. 
You should see something similar as below.
[image]

I hope this helps!
Reference: https://github.com/faisalman/ua-parser-js